# How to add custom filed to Django User Model

Tags: django, models

I am working on the project using django 1.9.

I need to add a field to the user model **'Auth_user'** table, the field which i want can be another primary key and act here as foreign key in the 'auth_user'.

I searched a lot but fails. Can any buddy provide me some example how to achieve this like how to to add fields to 'auth_user'

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute the user model entirely as described in [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user). Here is an example:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

to your `settings.py`, and add following to your model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    another_object = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel..
```

Answer (score 0):

just make a new moel with a user foreign key

```
class Post (models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   slug= models.SlugField(unique=True)
   content = models.TextField()
   user_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

there you can use as primary key the id of the post, or the slug (unique), and it can be linked to a user, if you need one to one relationship see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) or many to many relationship see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: thanks for the reply... but this is something that i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to extend de model user

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model